# Excel VBA: Toggle Buttons only work on right click

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working in Excel on a Userform.  Essentially, I want a "Photoshop-esque" toolbar that floats over my spreadsheet while I work, allowing me to select and use various tools.

I've got a series of toggle buttons set up so that when one is clicked, any other toggle buttons go back to unclicked.  It's a little more complicated because I have sub-buttons, if that makes sense, meaning that once I have a button clicked, I can click one of four other buttons to make my actual selection, and these four buttons are mutually exclusive from each other as well.

The weird thing: I haven't been able to get these buttons to work.  Except.  For some reason, when I right-click only, the buttons work like a charm.  Left-click: nothing.  Help please?

Sample button code:

```
Private Sub tMouse_MouseUp(ByVal button As Integer, _
       ByVal shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)


tMouse.Value = True
tActual.Value = False
tSched.Value = False
tX.Value = False
tDiam.Value = False
tCirc.Value = False
tTri.Value = False
tTrash.Value = False
tText.Value = False

End Sub
```

EDIT:
I tried what was suggested about printing the value of the toggle button.  And my computer blew up with messageboxes.  I had changed all the actions to Click() events.  Apparently I was sending the computer through an infinite loop.  Maybe the act of changing a button from true to false or vice versa acts like a click and triggers all the other click events?

Comment: There is nothing in what you have posted that would swallow the left mouse click.  Does the event fire when you press the left mouse button and nothing happens or is the event not even registering with a left mouse click?

Comment: When i click the toggle button with the left mouse button, it immediately untoggles.  If there is another button toggled true (done by right click) when I click a button with left click, that toggle button becomes false while the button I clicked cycles true and false again.

Comment: Do you have a mix of MouseUp and Click events for the same buttons?

Comment: No, I've always had either all MouseUp or all Click events.  And only one event per button.

Comment: have you tried setting a break point @ tMouse.Value and then stepping through each line to see if you're getting bounced somewhere unexpected that is changing the values?

Comment: *And my computer blew up with messageboxes.* Suggests that you're not properly handling the events. Do you have any other event procedures like `Change` events that could be contributing to this?

Comment: have a look here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SuppressChangeInForms.htm

Comment: No.  While stepping through, everytime I flipped a box from true to false or vice versa it popped right back to the top of the Sub.  When I said message box, I meant the one that told me the value of the toggle button.  I'd click ok and it would pop another one of the same thing, signifying a sub running over and over.

Comment: @sous2817 That was basically the greatest.  It worked perfect.  Pop that as the answer and I'll check it up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have events that are triggering other events.  What you'll need to do is set a Boolean AllowEventsToRun variable (either at the module or public level) and set that to false at the start of your code.  Run whatever you need to do, and then set it to true at the end.

The trick is to do an if statement to make sure that AllowEventsToRun is set to true before any other code is running.  Be sure to initialize the Boolean to true when you load your userform (since the default value of a boolean is false.  So something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private AllowEventsToRun As Boolean

Private Sub ToggleButton1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
If AllowEventsToRun Then

    AllowEventsToRun = False

    'whatever you're doing that's causing the events to chain fire

    AllowEventsToRun = True
End If

End Sub


Private Sub ToggleButton2_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
If AllowEventsToRun Then

    AllowEventsToRun = False

    'whatever you're doing that's causing the events to chain fire

    AllowEventsToRun = True
End If
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
AllowEventsToRun = True
End Sub
```

source: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SuppressChangeInForms.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an "Option" Control instead of a "Toggle" Control. 
If you stick 4 options in 1 frame then only 1 of those 4 options will allow itself to be true at a time automatically. You should use the "ToggleButton" control only if you want multiple instances of it to be true at the same time.

However if you refuse to do so and just really want to use ToggleButtons. Then you could write a procedure that is executed once pressing the button that sends it's name (or something else that identifies it uniquely) as a parameter to a procedure that sets all other togglebuttons false except it.

Cheers!

[image: Form Reference]

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    Dim s As String
    s = "ToggleButton1"
    Evaluate_Options s
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton2_Click()
    Dim s As String
    s = "ToggleButton2"
    Evaluate_Options s
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton3_Click()
    Dim s As String
    s = "ToggleButton3"
    Evaluate_Options s
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton4_Click()
    Dim s As String
    s = "ToggleButton4"
    Evaluate_Options s
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton5_Click()
    Dim s As String
    s = "ToggleButton5"
    Evaluate_Options s
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton6_Click()
    Dim s As String
    s = "ToggleButton6"
    Evaluate_Options s
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton7_Click()
    Dim s As String
    s = "ToggleButton7"
    Evaluate_Options s
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton8_Click()
    Dim s As String
    s = "ToggleButton8"
    Evaluate_Options s
End Sub

Private Sub Evaluate_Options(s As String)
    Dim tgl As Control

    For Each tgl In UserForm1.Frame1.Controls
        If InStr(tgl.Name, s) Then Set_Toggles_1 tgl
    Next
    For Each tgl In UserForm1.Frame2.Controls
        If InStr(tgl.Name, s) Then Set_Toggles_2 tgl
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Set_Toggles_1(tglTrue As Control)
    Dim tglFalse As Control
    For Each tglFalse In UserForm1.Frame1.Controls
        If tglFalse.Name = tglTrue.Name Then tglFalse = True Else tglFalse = False
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Set_Toggles_2(tglTrue As Control)
Dim tglFalse As Control
    For Each tglFalse In UserForm1.Frame2.Controls
        If tglFalse.Name = tglTrue.Name Then tglFalse = True Else tglFalse = False
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure Option buttons would be exactly the functionality I want, but I think the aesthetic of the toggle buttons will work nicer for what I'm doing.  Thanks though!  I'm too new to this site to upvote, but I'm upvoting in spirit :)

Comment: Sure thing. Glad to help. =D

Answer (score 0):

Try these basic mouse event capture subs and modify to suit your needs (tMouse = toggle button name):

```
Private Sub tMouse_Click()
'MsgBox "tb value = " & tMouse.Value
End Sub
```

Note: upper sub will not work, if lower sub called

```
Private Sub tMouse_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

If Button = 1 Then MsgBox "Left"
If Button = 2 Then MsgBox "Right"
End Sub
```

Comment: This gives new information, thanks!  See edit to my original post.